# Vk-api ошибка vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [15] Access denied: no access to call this method

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Пишу вк api для анонимного общения.
Использую библиотеку vk-api. При попытке отправить сообщение выводит ошибку

```
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [15] Access denied: no access to call this method
```

где бы я не копировал начальный код для простой отправки сообщения всё равно выходит.
Вот код:

```
from vk_api import VkApi, AuthError
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id

login = "Логин"
password = "Пароль"
vk_session = VkApi(login, password)
vk_session.auth(token_only=True)

vk = vk_session.get_api()

vk.messages.send(user_id="Id кому надо отправить", message='Сообщение', 
random_id=get_random_id())
```

Comment: Что-нибудь из этого принимали во внимание? https://vk.com/dev/messages_api, https://vk.com/faq11712, https://vk.com/dev/permissions

Comment: Скорее всего Вы вводите неправильный логин или пароль

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых: надо создать [приложение.](https://vk.com/dev/access_token)
Во-вторых: Метод messages.send можно вызвать с ключом доступа пользователя, полученным в [Standalone-приложении](https://vk.com/apps?act=manage) через [Implicit Flow](https://vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user). Требуются права доступа: messages.