# Ошибка LongPoll Python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

При активации кода вк бота для бесед выводит большую ошибку и.. как её пофиксить?
код:

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = "тут токен")
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, тут айди группы)

def sender(id, text):
     vk_session.method('messages.send', {'chat_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id' : 0})

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
       if event.from_chat:

        id = event.chat_id
        msg = event.object.message['text'].lower()

        if msg == 'ку':
            sender(id, 'привет')
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Games\bottest2.py", line 5, in <module>
    longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, 206146581)
  File "C:\Users\Дима\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\vk_api\bot_longpoll.py", line 218, in __init__
    self.update_longpoll_server()
  File "C:\Users\Дима\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\vk_api\bot_longpoll.py", line 231, in update_longpoll_server
    response = self.vk.method('groups.getLongPollServer', values)
  File "C:\Users\Дима\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 646, in method
    raise error
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [15] Access denied: no access to call this method
```

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1232821/vk-api-ошибка-vk-api-exceptions-apierror-15-access-denied-no-access-to-call

Comment: @Tehnorobot В приведённом Вами вопросе речь о User Long Poll API. Автор же использует Bots Long Poll API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка произошла при вызове метода [`getLongPollServer`](https://vk.com/dev/groups.getLongPollServer) и означает, что у Вас недостаточно прав.

Проверьте, что у Вашего токена есть права `manage`:

[image: Create an access token]

Также убедитесь, что Long Poll API активно:

[image: Long Poll API]